# Fontawesome 5, Missing fa-brands.svg?

Tags: svg, fonts, icons, font-awesome-5

I tried `Fontawesome 5` by replacing the old ones. I copied already the files

from the folder `web-fonts-with-css` to my  practice folder-> css. and link my page to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome.min.css">
```

And included the`fonts` (from Fontawesome) folder to my work folder.

[image: fa icons]

[image: google dev]

but from the fonts folder (extracted Fontawesome 5.0.8) **I didn't see fa-brands.svg .**

[image: fonts]

**EDIT:**
I still get the same error, I copied the `fa-brands.svg` from the folder `advanced-options` -> `svg-sprites`as suggested from the documentation page.

Comment: This sounds like something you should have asked over on https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome before asking here.